# Transition metal and complexation

Tags: coordination-compounds, transition-metals

When can we say that such metal forms a complex?

Are $\ce{Pd(OAc)2}$ and $\ce{Pd(PPh3)2Cl2}$ complexes?

Comment: Yes, they are. Most so called salts are actually polymeric complexes.

Answer (score 2):

Both of these compounds are **coordination complexes**. The label `complex` is preferred by many chemists because despite the appearance of some of these compounds as simple ionic compounds, they often display much more complex bonding motifs.

For example in $\ce{Pd(PPh3)2Cl2}$, there are two neutral ligands, $\ce{PPh3}$ that interact with the metal center through dative bonds. There is also evidence that the $\ce{Pd-Cl}$ bond is more covalent than ionic, since palladium forms a complex ion $\ce{PdCl4^-}$ with chlorine.

Palladium acetate man seem like a more clear cut case until you look at the crystal structure. Each acetate anion bridges two palladium, centers in a polymeric chain:

[image]

> It is worth noting that IUPAC does not recommend using the term `complex` to describe these compounds given that [complex](http://goldbook.iupac.org/C01203.html) can refer to a number of other, more loosely bound, species. IUPAC prefers [coordination entity](http://goldbook.iupac.org/C01330.html), though I have never heard a practicing chemist or seen a textbook use that phrase.